# Node.js not allowing CA cert from an api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, ca

I keep getting UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

When I set rejectUnauthorized: false, it connects and makes the request. Then it sends back the correct data.

I am using [Node's https request function](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html).

My CA is set up like so in side my options object:

```
ca: [fs.readFileSync('path/to/ca.pem')]
```

I am aware of the update to Node .10.10 that it doesn't not accept self signed certs. Is there away to force it to accept this ca that I have defined without setting rejectUnauthorized or export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="0" (second option didn't even work anyway).

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to set the rejectUnauthorized option to be false. 
The default of this option was changed since [Version 0.9.2](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/6e2055)

I assume you can create an agent with the ca specified.

Comment: I have already tried that. I know that it allows you to get make the request but it is not a secure connection.

Comment: Did you try something like `https.request({agent: yourAgent, ca: [yourCa]}, ... )`? Or that is not what you want.

Comment: Here are the options I pass in: https.request.                       var options = {
  host: '',
  port: ,
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('')],
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  path: '',
  method: '',
  headers: {"User-Agent":""}, 
  auth: ""
};